# Reshaping an array to data.frame

Tags: r, transform, dataframe, reshape

I have  the following data structure (an "atomic vector?") output from `daply` in  `plyr`, in which I had the function return three different measures for each subject, condition, and item.

```
x = structure(c(-0.93, 0.39, 0.88, 0.63, 0.86, -0.69, 1.02, 0.29, 0.94, 
0.93, -0.01, 0.79, 0.32, 0.14, 0.13, -0.07, -0.63, 0.26, 0.07, 0.87,
-0.36, 1.043, 0.33, -0.12, -0.055, 0.07, 0.67, 0.48, 0.002, 0.008, 
-0.19, -1.39, 0.98, 0.43, -0.02, -0.15,-0.08, 0.74, 0.96, 0.44, -0.005,
1.09, 0.36, 0.04, 0.09, 0.17, 0.68, 0.51, 0.09, 0.12, -0.05, 0.11,
0.99, 0.62, 0.13, 0.06, 0.27, 0.74, 0.96, 0.45), .Dim = c(5L, 
2L, 2L, 3L), .Dimnames = structure(list(Subject = c("s1", "s2", 
"s3", "s4", "s5"), Cond = c("A", "B"), Item = c("1", "2"), c("Measure1", 
"Measure2", "Measure3")), .Names = c("Subject", "Cond", 
"Item", "")))
```

I want to change it to look like:

```
Subject Cond Item Measure1 Measure2 Measure3
     s1    A    1    -0.93   -0.360   -0.005
     s1    A    2    -0.01    -0.19    -0.05 
     s1    B    1    -0.69    0.070     0.17
     s1    B    2    -0.07    -0.15     0.06
     s2    A    1     0.39    1.043    1.090
     s2    A    2     0.79    -1.39     0.11
     s2    B    1     1.02    0.670     0.68
     s2    B    2    -0.63    -0.08     0.27
```

etc.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: By the way, your data structure is an array. I know that because `*aply` will always return an array. Also, I know how to use `str(x)` and read the results.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, use `adply()`:

```
adply(x, c(1,2,3))
   Subject Cond Item Measure1 Measure2 Measure3
1       s1    A    1    -0.93   -0.360   -0.005
2       s2    A    1     0.39    1.043    1.090
3       s3    A    1     0.88    0.330    0.360
4       s4    A    1     0.63   -0.120    0.040
5       s5    A    1     0.86   -0.055    0.090
6       s1    B    1    -0.69    0.070    0.170
7       s2    B    1     1.02    0.670    0.680
8       s3    B    1     0.29    0.480    0.510
9       s4    B    1     0.94    0.002    0.090
10      s5    B    1     0.93    0.008    0.120
11      s1    A    2    -0.01   -0.190   -0.050
12      s2    A    2     0.79   -1.390    0.110
13      s3    A    2     0.32    0.980    0.990
14      s4    A    2     0.14    0.430    0.620
15      s5    A    2     0.13   -0.020    0.130
16      s1    B    2    -0.07   -0.150    0.060
17      s2    B    2    -0.63   -0.080    0.270
18      s3    B    2     0.26    0.740    0.740
19      s4    B    2     0.07    0.960    0.960
20      s5    B    2     0.87    0.440    0.450
```

Comment: Is there a faster alternative to this?

Comment: Also, is there an alternative using "base" R ? --> answer by @gjabel  (makes much more sense as it's all just basic R).

Answer (score 40):

Use `as.data.frame.table()`.

```
d0 <- as.data.frame.table(x)
head(d0)

#   Subject Cond Item     Var4  Freq
# 1      s1    A    1 Measure1 -0.93
# 2      s2    A    1 Measure1  0.39
# 3      s3    A    1 Measure1  0.88
# 4      s4    A    1 Measure1  0.63
# 5      s5    A    1 Measure1  0.86
# 6      s1    B    1 Measure1 -0.69

library(tidyr)
d1 <- pivot_wider(data = d0, names_from = "Var4", values_from = "Freq")
head(d1)

#   Subject Cond Item Measure1 Measure2 Measure3
# 1      s1    A    1    -0.93   -0.360   -0.005
# 2      s1    A    2    -0.01   -0.190   -0.050
# 3      s1    B    1    -0.69    0.070    0.170
# 4      s1    B    2    -0.07   -0.150    0.060
# 5      s2    A    1     0.39    1.043    1.090
# 6      s2    A    2     0.79   -1.390    0.110
```

Comment: This is also much faster than `adply`

Comment: Base R equivalent of the 2nd step: `reshape(d0, idvar = c('Subject', 'Cond', 'Item'), timevar = 'Var4', direction = "wide")`

Answer (score 4):

`df = melt(x)` gives you something very similar to what you want. Then you could compute the various measure variables from the different levels of measure.

Using the "reshape2" package, try:

```
dcast(melt(x), Subject + Cond + Item ~ Var4)
```

Comment: `melt` is much faster than `adply`. I have a very large dataset read from a NetCDF file, `adply` couldn't finish without crashing while `melt` created my dataframe in less than a second.

Answer (score 4):

`ftable` pretty much gets you where you need to be:

```
y <- ftable(x)
y
#
#                    Measure1 Measure2 Measure3
# Subject Cond Item                            
# s1      A    1       -0.930   -0.360   -0.005
#              2       -0.010   -0.190   -0.050
#         B    1       -0.690    0.070    0.170
#              2       -0.070   -0.150    0.060
# s2      A    1        0.390    1.043    1.090
#              2        0.790   -1.390    0.110
#         B    1        1.020    0.670    0.680
#              2       -0.630   -0.080    0.270
# s3      A    1        0.880    0.330    0.360
#              2        0.320    0.980    0.990
#         B    1        0.290    0.480    0.510
#              2        0.260    0.740    0.740
# s4      A    1        0.630   -0.120    0.040
#              2        0.140    0.430    0.620
#         B    1        0.940    0.002    0.090
#              2        0.070    0.960    0.960
# s5      A    1        0.860   -0.055    0.090
#              2        0.130   -0.020    0.130
#         B    1        0.930    0.008    0.120
#              2        0.870    0.440    0.450
```

---

But, most people would probably prefer their data in a `data.frame`. Using `as.data.frame.matrix` extracts the values, but not the row and column names. `ftable` stores that information in `row.vars` and `col.vars` attributes.

```
attributes(y)$row.vars
# $Subject
# [1] "s1" "s2" "s3" "s4" "s5"
# 
# $Cond
# [1] "A" "B"
# 
# $Item
# [1] "1" "2"

attributes(y)$col.vars
# [[1]]
# [1] "Measure1" "Measure2" "Measure3"
```

We can use this information to write a function that converts an `ftable` to a `data.frame`:

```
ftable2df <- function(mydata) {
  ifelse(class(mydata) == "ftable", 
         mydata <- mydata, mydata <- ftable(mydata))
  dfrows <- rev(expand.grid(rev(attr(mydata, "row.vars"))))
  dfcols <- as.data.frame.matrix(mydata)
  names(dfcols) <- do.call(
    paste, c(rev(expand.grid(rev(attr(mydata, "col.vars")))), sep = "_"))
  cbind(dfrows, dfcols)
}
```

Here it is in use directly on your original "x":

```
ftable2df(x)
#    Subject Cond Item Measure1 Measure2 Measure3
# 1       s1    A    1    -0.93   -0.360   -0.005
# 2       s1    A    2    -0.01   -0.190   -0.050
# 3       s1    B    1    -0.69    0.070    0.170
# 4       s1    B    2    -0.07   -0.150    0.060
# 5       s2    A    1     0.39    1.043    1.090
# 6       s2    A    2     0.79   -1.390    0.110
# 7       s2    B    1     1.02    0.670    0.680
# 8       s2    B    2    -0.63   -0.080    0.270
# 9       s3    A    1     0.88    0.330    0.360
# 10      s3    A    2     0.32    0.980    0.990
# 11      s3    B    1     0.29    0.480    0.510
# 12      s3    B    2     0.26    0.740    0.740
# 13      s4    A    1     0.63   -0.120    0.040
# 14      s4    A    2     0.14    0.430    0.620
# 15      s4    B    1     0.94    0.002    0.090
# 16      s4    B    2     0.07    0.960    0.960
# 17      s5    A    1     0.86   -0.055    0.090
# 18      s5    A    2     0.13   -0.020    0.130
# 19      s5    B    1     0.93    0.008    0.120
# 20      s5    B    2     0.87    0.440    0.450
```

Comment: In ftable2df the ifese could be written as   `if (!inherits(mydata, "ftable")) mydata <- ftable(mydata)`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the more generic `array2DF`, that was introduced in `R 4.3.0`:

```r
reshape(array2DF(x), idvar = c('Subject', 'Cond', 'Item'), timevar = 'Var4', direction = "wide")

#    Subject Cond Item Value.Measure1 Value.Measure2 Value.Measure3
# 1       s1    A    1          -0.93         -0.360         -0.005
# 2       s2    A    1           0.39          1.043          1.090
# 3       s3    A    1           0.88          0.330          0.360
# 4       s4    A    1           0.63         -0.120          0.040
# 5       s5    A    1           0.86         -0.055          0.090
# 6       s1    B    1          -0.69          0.070          0.170
# 7       s2    B    1           1.02          0.670          0.680
# 8       s3    B    1           0.29          0.480          0.510
# 9       s4    B    1           0.94          0.002          0.090
# 10      s5    B    1           0.93          0.008          0.120
# 11      s1    A    2          -0.01         -0.190         -0.050
# 12      s2    A    2           0.79         -1.390          0.110
# 13      s3    A    2           0.32          0.980          0.990
# 14      s4    A    2           0.14          0.430          0.620
# 15      s5    A    2           0.13         -0.020          0.130
# 16      s1    B    2          -0.07         -0.150          0.060
# 17      s2    B    2          -0.63         -0.080          0.270
# 18      s3    B    2           0.26          0.740          0.740
# 19      s4    B    2           0.07          0.960          0.960
# 20      s5    B    2           0.87          0.440          0.450
```