# Name group of dimensions in array

Tags: r, arrays

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11141406/12400385) question the object `x` (pasted below) is an `array`*. `x` has an argument called `.Dimnames` and another called `.Names`, which seems to name each grouping of `.Dimnames`. When `x` is converted to a `data.frame` the `values` in `.Names` become the column names.

`.Dimnames` seems to be analogous to `array(dimnames)`, but I can't find the analogous `array` argument for `.Names`.

```
# object from the linked question

x = structure(c(-0.93, 0.39, 0.88, 0.63, 0.86, -0.69, 1.02, 0.29, 0.94, 
0.93, -0.01, 0.79, 0.32, 0.14, 0.13, -0.07, -0.63, 0.26, 0.07, 0.87,
-0.36, 1.043, 0.33, -0.12, -0.055, 0.07, 0.67, 0.48, 0.002, 0.008, 
-0.19, -1.39, 0.98, 0.43, -0.02, -0.15,-0.08, 0.74, 0.96, 0.44, -0.005,
1.09, 0.36, 0.04, 0.09, 0.17, 0.68, 0.51, 0.09, 0.12, -0.05, 0.11,
0.99, 0.62, 0.13, 0.06, 0.27, 0.74, 0.96, 0.45), .Dim = c(5L, 
2L, 2L, 3L), .Dimnames = structure(list(Subject = c("s1", "s2", 
"s3", "s4", "s5"), Cond = c("A", "B"), Item = c("1", "2"), c("Measure1", 
"Measure2", "Measure3")), .Names = c("Subject", "Cond", 
"Item", "")))
```

When I convert `x` using `as.data.frame.table` the column names are meaningful. E.g.

```
head(as.data.frame.table(x))

#-----
  Subject Cond Item     Var4  Freq
1      s1    A    1 Measure1 -0.93
2      s2    A    1 Measure1  0.39
3      s3    A    1 Measure1  0.88
4      s4    A    1 Measure1  0.63
5      s5    A    1 Measure1  0.86
6      s1    B    1 Measure1 -0.69
```

If I have another array `y`, how do I name a group of dimensions so that when I convert to a `data.frame` the column names are meaningful? E.g

```
y <- array(1:9,
      dim = c(3,3,3),
      dimnames = list(letters[1:3],
                      LETTERS[1:3],
                      month.abb[1:3]))

as.data.frame.table(y)

#---------
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Freq
1    a    A  Jan    1
2    b    A  Jan    2
3    c    A  Jan    3
4    a    B  Jan    4
5    b    B  Jan    5
6    c    B  Jan    6
```

*Note: `str(x)` does not say `array`, but `x` behaves like an array. Maybe I need to convert to a different data structure?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *"column names are meaningful"*? I think that `Subject`, `Cond`, `Item`, or `Freq` are meaningful enough ... only `Var4` seems uninformative to me.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I am just using `x` as an example. How would I apply names like `Subject` or `Cond` to a different array?

Comment: `ary <- array(1:24, dim=c(2,3,4)); dimnames(ary) <- list(a=c(),b=c(),d=c())`? Perhaps I'm missing something, my apologies.

Comment: Ah, simple fix. Didn't realize you could put a name on the left hand side of an `=` in `dimnames`. If you wanted to put your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign names of the dimensions without naming the actual rows/columns/pipes. (I think the 3rd margin is called a "pipe", not to be confused with `%>%` which is not a pipe ;-)

```r
ary <- array(1:24, dim=c(2,3,4))
dimnames(ary) <- list(a=c(),b=c(),d=c())
ary
# , , 1
#       b
# a      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#   [1,]    1    3    5
#   [2,]    2    4    6
# , , 2
#       b
# a      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#   [1,]    7    9   11
#   [2,]    8   10   12
# , , 3
#       b
# a      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#   [1,]   13   15   17
#   [2,]   14   16   18
# , , 4
#       b
# a      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#   [1,]   19   21   23
#   [2,]   20   22   24
```

Comment: Defining `a`, `b` and `d` in your example is what I was looking for. After you pointed it out I now see in the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/array) for `dimname` says *The list can be named, and the list names will be used as names for the dimensions*.